# Spark Structured Streaming writeStream to output one global csv

Tags: scala, spark-streaming

I am currently making a raw log data aggregator using Spark Structured Streaming.

The Inputstream is made with a directory of text files :

```
// == Input == //

val logsDF = spark.readStream
  .format("text")
  .option("maxFilesPerTrigger", 1)
  .load("input/*")
```

Logs are then parsed ...

```
// == Parsing == //

val logsDF2 = ...
```

... and aggregated

```
// == Aggregation == //

val windowedCounts = logsDF2
  .withWatermark("window_start", "15 minutes")
  .groupBy(
    col("window"),
    col("node")
  ).count()
```

Everything is working fine when I use the "console" sink : The results are updated batch by bath in the console :

```
// == Output == //

val query = windowedCounts.writeStream
  .format("console")
  .outputMode("complete")
  .start()
  .awaitTermination()
```

Now I want to save my results in one unique file (json, parquet, csv ..)

```
// == Output == //

val query = windowedCounts.writeStream
  .format("csv")
  .option("checkpointLocation", "checkpoint/")
  .start("output/")
  .awaitTermination()
```

But it outputs me 400 empty csv ... How can I get my results as I did in the console ?

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 5):

Long time ago, but ran through this issue myself and thought I would solve it. Indeed, I think your code is good until you try to sink the data into a csv file. Try changing the writeStream csv code to this:

```
// == Output == //
val query = windowedCounts.writeStream
  .format("csv")
  .trigger(processingTime="10 seconds")
  .option("checkpointLocation", "checkpoint/")
  .option("path", "output_path/")
  .outputMode("append")
  .start()
  .awaitTermination()
```

The line:

```
.trigger(processingTime="10 seconds")
```

should solve your 400 files as it only writes a new file every 10 seconds. Both of these lines:

```
.option("path", "output_path/")
.outputMode("append")
```

should solve the empty file problem as you append the latest values and output the file into a specific output directory.

Comment: `append` mode doesnt really make sence  since some keys need to be updated over time